# Fluid, object, childof constraint animation - won't work

Tags: fluid-simulation

[See this video for project example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1iTMcsX-Xg)

It's a simple project. I'm trying to create a fluid simulation flow out of a cylinder, but the cylinder has a "childof" constraint, paired to the cube above it. The cylinder moves, but the fluid simulation does not; it stays in the "actual" position of the cylinder.

Is there a way I can accomplish having the fluid simulation follow the cylinder, even with a childof constraint? Or is there some other way to accomplish this task?

(Using Blender 2.75a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of how blender works, constraints are the last step to placing an object, which means the fluid sim will never see the inflow object in the constrained location.

The way to get this working is to bake the animation into keyframes for the inflow object then remove the constraint. *Object->Animation->Bake Action...* will do this for you.

[image]

You want to turn on visual keying so that you get the location after the constraint is applied.

[image]