# How to make Fluid Inflow follow bone?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, fluid-simulation

I have made a very simple scne to test Fluids where there are two containers and a moving tap. Basically, the tap moves to one contianer and fills it up, then it stops and moves to the other container and fills it up. I've managed to make the flow stop and start, but for some reason, the fluid doesn't follow the tap.

I parented the fluid origin object(Sphere) and it follows, but when it's time to release the fluid, it just doesn't follow.

How can I make everything follow the bone?

Here is the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly2g8j6hipmeain/FLUID_TEST.blend1?dl=0

Comment: I've never done fluids, but particle emitters can be moved and the particles follow the emitter.  Stopping and starting the same emitter I've not tried either.  Recently I had to make 8 emitters placed as in an array in order to do what you are attempting, one for each step, each starting/stopping at their appointed frames to emulate emitter movement.

Comment: That is a limit of the fluid sim - you need to animate the location of the inflow object. You could parent or use a copy location constraint and then [bake it](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38054/935) if you have some complex movement already done. Animate the enabled option of the inflow to turn it on/off.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was trying to do things the hard way. I can just keyframe the Sphere itselft and move it around as I need to, withouth having to make it follow the armature.

So it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just by the way, because I also had a similar problem where I decided to "simplify" my animation (which was already working) by parenting my fluid inflow object into a container (a cup, from which fluid would flow out in the animation, and the inflow object was hidden (not rendered)). After I parented it, the fluid started flowing from a different location than the inflow object. In fact, the fluid flowed from the final location of the object at the end of the animation. Looking it up, I found this: https://developer.blender.org/T36902

Which clarifies that, in cases where you are parenting an inflow object where the parent changes location (if it's just rotation it is not necessary):

> "you simply have to enable "Export Animated Mesh" for the inflow object"

I started the bake and can confirm this fixed it in my case. Hope that helps others out there.