# Can animations created with Animation Nodes be exported to Unity3D

Tags: animation-nodes

If I have a rigged character in Blender and use [Animation Nodes add-on](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) to create a walking and a running animation. Can I export that character with those animations to Unity3D? If so, is there any documentation on how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Try using [bake action](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38054/935)

Comment: How do you create those "animation" in animation nodes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @sambler.

Comment: @OmarAhmad you'll see in the original question that there is a link. When you click on that link you will be taken to the github page of the add-on, it's a powerful animation tool. What I'm trying to find out is whether the animations created with that add-on can be exported into Unity3D, thanks

Comment: I'm not certain that it will bake the result of animation nodes, but the bake action can turn constraint based animations into keyframes that can be exported. If it does bake the animation you have done then you can export it to unity.

Comment: @davomcdavo I know what AN is, I have been using it for quite some time. I need you to tell me what kind of animation do you have in AN. Show us node trees, blend files, anything.

Comment: Ahh I see @sambler that makes sense, thank you, I'll give that a go. I'm new to blender but I will be working with my team-mate who already created the assets, I'll try to help him animating them.

Comment: Hi @OmarAhmad, oh I see, sorry. The animations that I'm planning to create will be on the bones of a rigged character built by my team-mate.