# Blender 2.8 Viewport object visibility problem

Tags: animation, 3d-view, drivers, eevee-render-engine

I have this annoying problem to which I can't seem to find a solution

Is there a way to enable in viewport **to display rendered only objects**, check out image below to see what I mean.[image]
[image]

In 2.79 it was possible to link object visibility via drivers, so viewport would display in real time the objects that would be rendered (by linking visibility to render via driver). But in 2.8 visibility cannot be animated anymore!

Is there any hidden option that allows me to do this what I want? please help me out because I've been looking for hours

Thanks!

Comment: what is the expression used in the driver for this to happen? asking for my own use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a driver for visibility properties works in the current build of blender. There are some related changes that may be affect what you are trying to do.

In 2.7x pressing <kbd>D</kbd> adds a driver to the property under the cursor, in 2.80 that is now <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to add a driver.

In 2.7x the property `hide` will hide the object in the viewport, in 2.80 that is now called `hide_viewport` so scripts or drivers may need to be updated with this change.

Comment: what is the script used in the driver for this to happen?

Comment: @NickSieben Setup hide_viewport [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6e34.jpg). You can enable Use Self and enter `self.hide_render` but it shows it as a slow python expression.

Comment: Also note, that this is a one way dependency. We can add a driver to hide_viewport so that it is the same as hide_render but not the other way.

Comment: Alright thank you

Comment: Is it possible to bake drivers into keyframes?

Comment: @NickSieben in the 3d view use [Object->Animation->Bake Action](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38054/935) and ensure visual keying is enabled.